# How to update Userform contents as code progresses

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having an issue where I have some vba code that runs different functions. I have built out a userform that keeps the user updated on the progress. This isn't a progress bar. It is simply changing a label text. However, when I run it, nothing changes. The code does not finish until I exit out of the userform. Does anyone know how to fix this? The code is listed below. Thanks!

```
frmALL.Show
xUpload ("DEV")
frmALL.devProgress.Caption = "Complete!"
frmALL.devProgress.ForeColor = vbGreen
frmALL.qaProgress.Caption = "Uploading"
xUpload ("QA")
frmALL.qaProgress.Caption = "Complete!"
frmALL.qaProgress.ForeColor = vbGreen
frmALL.prodProgress.Caption = "Uploading"
xUpload ("PROD")
frmALL.prodProgress.Caption = "Complete!"
frmALL.prodProgress.ForeColor = vbGreen
frmALL.Header.Caption = "Success!"
```

devProgress, prodProgress and qaProgress all repersent labels in the userform. When I set the forms showModal=false, then it just appears as a white screen until it's done with the code then shows all "Success". This is an issue because it doesn't show the progress like I thought it would. Does my code run too fast? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want other activities to occur while the Userform is active, you will need to load the form as modeless, `frmAll.Show vbModeless`

Comment: @Cyril I just tried this. It doesn't work like I expected. When it first loads, it is just a white screen. When the code runs thru and is complete, then it updates and shows "Success" on each one. However, it doesn't show any progress in between them. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Your code will have to be written to "trigger" your different lines.  Modeless will allow other operations to occur while the form is shown, so all of the code in the module you have provided is run while the form is loaded.  It may be more appropriate to have form-change events going, e.g., `private sub combobox1_change()` where if you select somethign in combobox 1, the value is changed and it triggers soemthign to happen (like a label update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will try to give a quick example of the `_Change()` usage based on your code:

```
Sub Open_UserForm()
    'make sure you have a userform_initialize subroutine for base info
    frmALL.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

In the code for your userform, you might have:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'ASSUMES DEVPROGRESS IS TRIGGERED BY COMBOBOX1 VALUE CHANGE
    xUpload ("DEV")
    frmALL.devProgress.Caption = "Complete!"
    frmALL.devProgress.ForeColor = vbGreen
    frmALL.qaProgress.Caption = "Uploading"
End Sub
```

---

**Example images... background code for my exmaple:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("cat", "dog")
End Sub

Private Sub combobox1_change()
    Label1.Caption = "label 1 = updated"
End Sub
```

Userform from beginning (pressed F5 from IDE to launch):

[image]

Me selecting something in combobox 1:

[image]

Combobox1 value changed, label updated:

[image]

Comment: Note that I didn't need to make my form modeless for this as the form-change events did the work.  The `vbmodeless` in my original comment was targeted at your use of things "after" the `.show` so they would be all run.